# Adding image upload field to admin form

Tags: magento2, admin, image-upload

I'm trying to add an image upload field to the admin module form so admin users can have a profile picture, I've managed to add a column in the database through the installSchema but can't work out how to add the upload button and save the image on the frontend.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7):

Add Below code in n `_prepareForm()` function inside

> app/code/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Tab/Main.php

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'profile',
    'image',
    [
        'name' => 'profile',
        'label' => __('Profile Image'),
        'title' => __('Profile Image'),
        'required'  => false,
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

Now in `execute()` method of your save controller file. use below code to save and upload image.

> app/code/Namespace/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php

`use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;`

```
$profileImage = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('profile');
$fileName = ($profileImage && array_key_exists('name', $profileImage)) ? $profileImage['name'] : null;
if ($profileImage && $fileName) {
    try {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
            ['fileId' => 'profile']
        );
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapterFactory */
        $imageAdapterFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')
            ->create();
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
            ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

        $result = $uploader->save(
            $mediaDirectory
                ->getAbsolutePath('Modulename/Profile')
        );
        //$data['profile'] = 'Modulename/Profile/'. $result['file'];
        $model->setProfile('Modulename/Profile'.$result['file']); //Database field name
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 0) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer with explanation!!! +1 made my day :)